# Create counters for multiple Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, owl-carousel

I need to create multiple owl carousel slider, I need it to be globally same even if I add many sliders, this is working until I needed a counter over a slider.

So every slider has a counter, (1/5 or 1/9) that changes when its scrolled or clicked the nav button

Here is what i have but the counters are broken, its not independently working.

```
$(function(){
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
  autoplay: 2000,
  items:1,
  nav:true,
  loop: true,
  onInitialized  : counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
  onTranslated : counter //When the translation of the stage has finished.
});

function counter(event) {
   var element   = event.target;         // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
    var items     = event.item.count;     // Number of items
    var item      = event.item.index + 1;     // Position of the current item

  // it loop is true then reset counter from 1
  if(item > items) {
    item = item - items
  }
  $('#counter').html("item "+item+" of "+items)
}
});
```

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6esdf7mz/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

Actually the way you determine the current position works fine. The issue is updating the correct div with the counter information.

In your fiddle, it looks like you're searching for `.counter`, but what you should be searching for is the `.counter` that is a child of your carousel container.

### Solution:

```
$(element).parent().find('.counter').html("item " + item + " of " + items)
```

### Working example:

```js
$(function() {
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    autoplay: 2000,
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    loop: true,
    onInitialized: counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
    onTranslated: counter //When the translation of the stage has finished.
  });

  function counter(event) {
     
    var element = event.target; // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
    var items = event.item.count; // Number of items
    var item = event.item.index + 1; // Position of the current item

    // it loop is true then reset counter from 1
    if (item > items) {
      item = item - items
    }
    $(element).parent().find('.counter').html("item " + item + " of " + items)
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <!-- 4 items -->
    <div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=121" alt="img1" /></div>
    <div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=232" alt="img1" /></div>
    <div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=343" alt="img1" /></div>
    <div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=454" alt="img1" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="counter"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <!-- 3 items -->
    <div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=121" alt="img1" /></div>
    <div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=232" alt="img1" /></div>
    <div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=343" alt="img1" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="counter"></div>
</div>
```